# Data type incompatibility issue in Theano

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, theano, lasagne

I've got a dense dropout ANN with a softmax output layer. Here is the training method:

```
def train(network, input_var, epochs, train_input, val_input, batchsize,
          update_fn, loss_fn, verbose=True, deterministic=False, **kwargs):
    """
    :param network: the output layer of a `lasagne`-backed ANN
    :type input_var: TheanoVariable
    :param train_input: (x, y)
    :type train_input: (np.ndarray, np.ndarray)
    :param val_input: (x, y)
    :type val_input: (np.ndarray, np.ndarray)
    """

    # create target var
    # note: I use my own method instead of `theano.shared`, because for 
    #       whatever reason Theano says I can't use a shared variable here
    #       and that I should pass it via the `givens` parameter, whatever
    #       that is.
    target_var = self.numpy_to_theano_variable(train_input[1])

    # training functions
    prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network,
                                           deterministic=deterministic)
    loss = loss_fn(prediction, target_var).mean()
    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)
    updates = update_fn(loss, params, **kwargs)
    train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss, updates=updates)
    # validation functions
    val_pred = lasagne.layers.get_output(network, deterministic=True)
    val_loss = loss_fn(val_pred, target_var).mean()
    val_acc = T.mean(T.eq(T.argmax(val_pred, axis=1), target_var),
                     dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    val_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], [val_loss, val_acc])

    def run_epoch(epoch):
        train_batches = yield_batches(train_input, batchsize)
        val_batches = yield_batches(val_input, batchsize)
        train_err = np.mean([train_fn(x, y) for x, y in train_batches])
        val_err, val_acc = np.mean(
            [val_fn(x, y) for x, y in val_batches], axis=0)
        if verbose:
            print("Epoch {} of {}: training error = {}, "
                  "validation error = {}, validation accuracy = {}"
                  "".format(epoch+1, epochs, train_err, val_err, val_acc))
        return train_err, val_err, val_acc

    return [run_epoch(e) for e in xrange(epochs)]
```

The `numpy_to_theano_variable` method is defined in the base class:

```
def create_theano_variable(ndim, dtype, name=None):
    """
    :type ndim: int
    :type dtype: str
    :type name: str
    """
    if ndim == 1:
        theano_var = T.vector(name, dtype=dtype)
    elif ndim == 2:
        theano_var = T.matrix(name, dtype=dtype)
    elif ndim == 3:
        theano_var = T.tensor3(name, dtype=dtype)
    elif ndim == 4:
        theano_var = T.tensor4(name, dtype=dtype)
    else:
        raise ValueError
    return theano_var

def numpy_to_theano_variable(array, name=None):
    """
    :type array: np.ndarray
    :param array:
    :rtype: T.TensorVariable
    """
    return create_theano_variable(ndim=array.ndim,
                                  dtype=str(array.dtype).split(".")[-1],
                                  name=name)
```

In the beginning of `train` `target_var` is initialised as a `TheanoVariable` with the same number of dimensions and type as the numpy array used to feed it. For a reason beyond my comprehension, if the datatype is not `int32` or `int64` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./train_net.py", line 131, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./train_net.py", line 123, in main
    learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, verbose=True)
  File "/Users/ilia/OneDrive/GitHub/...", line 338, in train
    loss = loss_fn(prediction, target_var).mean()
  File "/Users/ilia/.venvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lasagne/objectives.py", line 129, in categorical_crossentropy
    return theano.tensor.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(predictions, targets)
  File "/Users/ilia/.venvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/nnet/nnet.py", line 2077, in categorical_crossentropy
    return crossentropy_categorical_1hot(coding_dist, true_dist)
  File "/Users/ilia/.venvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 613, in __call__
    node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ilia/.venvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/nnet/nnet.py", line 1440, in make_node
    tensor.lvector))
TypeError: integer vector required for argument: true_one_of_n(got type: TensorType(<dtype>, vector) instead of: TensorType(int64, vector))
```

where `<dtype>` represents the type of `target_var` inferred from the numpy array (I tested that with `int8`, `int16`, `uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, `uint64`). What is the reason it only takes `int32` and `int64`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the reason for that originates from Theano trying to be flexible by assuring your code is 100% compatible with both CPU and GPU backends at the same time. Since most versions of CUDA only support 32 and 64 bit arithmetic types, you can't use any other.